# Get Cordova Plugin Header File Path

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova

I created a cordova plugin, and I'm very new to this, please correct me if I'm using the wrong approach.

This is my problem.

Inside my plugin I declare a header file (an unix executable file) to be copy to my Xcode project, i declare it like this inside my plugin.xml, iOS platform

```
<header-file src="src/ios/lib-cat/cat"/>
```

Now, I'm trying to get the path for my "cat" file inside my objective c code, i tried

```
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cat"];
```

and i tried

```
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cat" ofType:nil];

NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cat" ofType:@""];

NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"cat" ofType:@"exec"];
```

None of them seems to be working. Could anyone provide me the right way of getting it's path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question,

I change

```
<header-file src="src/ios/lib-cat/cat"/>
```

to

```
<resource-file src="src/ios/lib-cat/cat"/>
```

and search it with

```
NSString *path = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"cat"];
```